# Highcharts xAxi title how left-aligned?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want it to appear to the left of the title so long padding。
Examples:http://jsfiddle.net/fFux3/

`title: {
                enabled: true,
                align: "low",
                offset :0,
                x : 120,
                text: 'Custom with <b>simple</b> <i>markup</i>',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                }
            }`

Comment: Could you show some image/mockup how should this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
offset: 0
```

that is causing the issue, here I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fFux3/1/

I hope this will help you